# Plotting Jaccard Index against spatial data (lat-long)

Tags: vegan, geosphere

I am trying to find a way to plot a matrix (In this case a matrix with jaccard indices) against spatial distances (I have latitude and longitude data). I have been told to use the "geosphere" package but I haven't been able to fully understand how to use it.

So if anyone here is well versed in doing such things, please help me out

kind regards

Comment: I should probably add, that I need the spatial distances converted to regular distance vectors in meters

Comment: There are many packages that can calculate great circle distances from longlat data. The oldest and most classical is the **sp** package that has function `spDists`. This returns great circle distances in meters. However, there are many others and more modern packages.

Answer (score 0):

Package **geosphere** is indeed a good choice as it is based on ellipsoid instead of a sphere and gives more accurate results than many other alternatives (and directly in metres). However, it is more tedious to use as it only calculates a distance between two points, or in a matrix, the track lengths from point to the next point instead of the full matrix. The following is an easy way that does a lot of unnecessary calculation that you throw away, but it is much simpler than alternatives (and sufficiently fast for any practical purpose).

Assume you have matrix `x` of dimensions N times 2, where the two columns are the longitude and latitude (in this order) in decimal degrees and N is the number of observations:

```
library(geosphere)
N <- NROW(x)
geodists <- matrix(0, N, N)
for (i in 1:N) for(j in 1:N) geodists[i,j] <- distGeo(x[i,], x[j,])
## alternative for only lower diagonal:
## for(j in 1:(N-1)) for(i in (j+1):N) geodists[i,j] <- distGeo(x[i,], x[j,])
geodists <- as.dist(geodists)
```

The `geodists` will then be arranged similarly as the Jaccard distances (assuming you used **vegan** or other package that returns standad `dist` structures) and these can be directly plotted against each other. If you used some package that gives you a matrix (which is symmetric and has zero diagonal), it is best to change the result to distances (`as.dist()`) which only have the lower triangle without the zero diagonal as these give nicer plots.

Package **sp** uses also WGS84 ellipsoid, but its results differ little (less than 0.01% in my test for distances up to 2500km) from those given by the **geosphere**. It may be that **geosphere** is more accurate (and it also allows alternatives to WGS84 ellipsoid). However, **sp** is much easier to use, and will give you directly the symmetric matrix of distances (but in kilometres instead of metres, though I claimed so in my comment), and you can do with one command:

```
library(sp)
geodists <- as.dist(spDists(x, longlat=TRUE))*1000 # in metres
```

Comment: `sp::spDists` uses the Meeus algorithm which is also available in `geosphere::distMeeus`, but `geosphere::distGeo` should be more accurate. Numerically `sp::spDists` and `geosphere::distMeeus` give identical results within numerical accuracy.